# Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.ScriptableObject' to `T'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class UVBaseTool : ScriptableObject, IPropertiesChanged
{
    private BaseToolProperties properties_;
    private ScriptableObject propertiesNoValidate_;

    // Some code ...

    protected void SetProperties(System.Type propertiesType, System.Type properties1Type)
    {
        properties_ = propertiesType == null ? null : CreateInstance(propertiesType) as BaseToolProperties;
        if (properties_ != null)
        {
            properties_.tool = (this);
        }

        propertiesNoValidate_ = properties1Type == null ? null : CreateInstance(properties1Type);
    }

    public T Properties<T>()
    {
        return properties_;
    }

    public T PropertiesNoValidate<T>()
    {
        return propertiesNoValidate_;
    }
}
```

Can Any one help me out with this as i am not able to resolve these errors:

1. Assets/Rocket/Archi/Scripts/Editor/UVEditor/UVBaseTool.cs(219,14): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Rocket.Archi.BaseToolProperties' to`T'
2. Assets/Rocket/Archi/Scripts/Editor/UVEditor/UVBaseTool.cs(224,14):
   error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type
   `UnityEngine.ScriptableObject' to`T'

I tried going through the online context for the CS0029 but still i cant seem to convert through IConvertable. Please let me know if there is a solution.

This is how i am calling to

```
[SerializeField]
private BaseToolProperties properties_;
[SerializeField]
private ScriptableObject propertiesNoValidate_;

public virtual void Start()
{
      EditorUtil.HideGlobalGizmo();
      ArchiEx.selectedElements.ClearVertexBoxes();
      ArchiEx.currentCamera = (Camera) null;
      GizmoHandler.Destroy();
      if (properties_ != null)
        EditorUtil.LoadObject(properties_, null);
      if (propertiesNoValidate_ != null)
        EditorUtil.LoadObject(propertiesNoValidate_, null);
      Ruler.Add(this, RulerType.Local);
      ArchiSettings.GatherArchi();
}
```

And this is the baseTool;

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Rocket.Archi
{
  [Serializable]
  public class BaseToolProperties : ScriptableObject
  {
    [NonSerialized]
    public IPropertiesChanged tool;

    public virtual void OnValidate()
    {
      if (tool == null)
        return;
      tool.OnPropertiesChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

[The Image Attached shows how i am calling Properties in other Classes and believe me there is no error in that part i have checked all the context again and again, but this generic function is killing me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBDbx.png)

The error Goes away if i write it like this but now i am getting another error which is for IConvertable. When ever i try to make an object in scene view i get this recurring error. See Below;

```
public T Properties<T>()
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(properties_, typeof(T));
    }

    public T PropertiesNoValidate<T>()
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(propertiesNoValidate_, typeof(T));
    }
```

InvalidCastException: Object must implement IConvertible.
System.Convert.ChangeType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at :0)
System.Convert.ChangeType (System.Object value, System.Type conversionType) (at :0)
RocketMod.Archi.BaseTool.Properties[T] () (at Assets/Rocket - Modelling Tools/Archi/Scripts/Editor/BaseTool.cs:224)
RocketMod.Archi.PropertiesGUI.HasContents () (at Assets/Rocket - Modelling Tools/Archi/Scripts/Editor/PropertiesGUI.cs:54)
RocketMod.Archi.PropertiesGUI.OnGUI () (at Assets/Rocket - Modelling Tools/Archi/Scripts/Editor/PropertiesGUI.cs:17)
RocketMod.Archi.ToolSelectionGUI.OnGUI () (at Assets/Rocket - Modelling Tools/Archi/Scripts/Editor/ToolSelectionGUI.cs:164)
RocketMod.Archi.ArchiEditor.OnInspectorGUI () (at Assets/Rocket - Modelling Tools/Archi/Scripts/Editor/ArchiEditor.cs:299)
UnityEditor.InspectorWindow.DrawEditor (UnityEditor.Editor[] editors, System.Int32 editorIndex, System.Boolean rebuildOptimizedGUIBlock, System.Boolean& showImportedObjectBarNext, UnityEngine.Rect& importedObjectBarRect) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/Inspector/InspectorWindow.cs:1253)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

if to solve this i  write as below everything stops working;

```
public T Properties<T>() where T : IConvertible
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(properties_, typeof(T));
    }

    public T PropertiesNoValidate<T>() where T : IConvertible
    {
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(propertiesNoValidate_, typeof(T));
    }
```

ANY HELP WOULD BE MUCH APPRECIATED GUYS !!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please pay attention when selecting tags. You selected the C language tag, instead of C#. You should also have added the `unit3d` tag.

Comment: There is **a lot** of code in your question, can you remove the parts that are irrevelant to the question? I doubt anyone will read your whole code to guess where your errors are

Comment: I am Getting these errors on these lines only

Comment: `T` is a generic type. `BaseToolProperties` is of type `ScriptableObject`. How exactly do you call `Properties()` in your other classes? Imagine using `Properties<int>()` how would you cast the `_properties` to `int` in order to return it?

Comment: For Example for Color i am calling it as Color color = Properties<VertexColorToolProperties>().color;

Comment: i have added some of the references listing for your understanding to my original post check the image link in the end... hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

You are using generic type `<T>` in your method that returns a specific typed property.

Replace the signature of your methods by theses :

```
//     v----------------v--------------The type of properties_
public BaseToolProperties Properties()
{   //                              ^----------------the <T> was removed
    return properties_;
}

//     v--------------v----------------The type of propertiesNoValidate_
public ScriptableObject PropertiesNoValidate()
{   //                                      ^--------the <T> was removed
    return propertiesNoValidate_;
}
```

Comment: This solves the error at hand but creates a problem as i am trying to create a mesh editing tool in unity. So to say these properties_ and propertiesNoValidate_ are being reflected from BaseMeshTool to other components as serializable fields in the package. So now all of them stopped working.

Comment: I'd like to see in your question post how you called `Properties<T>()` and `PropertiesNoValidate<T>()`

Comment: I am Getting this error with all the tools error CS0308: The non-generic method `Rocket.Archi.BaseTool.Properties()' cannot be used with the type arguments